# merge rows returned by group by clause into single row according to condition

Tags: sql

In SQL I have a query which is used to find type of error made by an employee.there are 3 types of errors that an employee can make- financial ,administrative and FYI errors.I have used group by clause with employeeid and error type but i want group by with employeeid only but in this case error is thrown that you have to include error type in group by because it is contaned in select list.

```
select i_empid,
    COUNT(i_empid) as claims_audited,
    sum(i_errcount) as total_errors,
    case 
        when c_errtype = 'FINANCIAL'
            then SUM(i_errcount)
        else 0
        end as financial_errors,
    case 
        when c_errtype = 'ADMINISTRATIVE'
            then SUM(i_errcount)
        else 0
        end as administrative_errors,
    case 
        when c_errtype = 'FYI'
            then SUM(i_errcount)
        else 0
        end as FYI_errors
from EL_Error_Mst
group by i_empid,
    c_errtype
```

I am getting result set like this:

```
i_empid claims_audited  total_errors    financial_errors    administrative_errors   FYI_errors  
13           1              1                  0                     1                0       
341          1               1                 0                     1                0   
665          2               2                 0                     2                0   
341          1               1                 1                     0                0
```

but i want single row for each employee that give each type of error made by him.how can I get this?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Pick one please.

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense. And it looks like this would pretty much provide the output you are looking for. Here is a great place to look at improving this question. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to revert the order of case and sum, and remove the group by c_errtype:

```
select i_empid, 
count(i_empid) as claims_audited
sum(case when c_errtype='FINANCIAL' then i_errcount else 0 end) as financial_errors,
sum(case when c_errtype='ADMINISTRATIVE' then i_errcount else 0 end) as administrative_errors,
sum(case when c_errtype='FYI' then i_errcount else 0 end) as fyi_errors
from EL_Error_Mst
group by i_empid
```

Comment: Again Iam getting the error.                     Column 'EL_Error_Mst.c_errtype' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

I think your error is being caused by how you are trying to sum your conditions. How about this?

```
select i_empid,
    count(i_empid) as claims_audited,
    sum(i_errcount) as total_errors,
    sum(case 
        when c_errtype = 'FINANCIAL'
            then i_errcount
        else 0
        end) as financial_errors,
    sum(case 
        when c_errtype = 'ADMINISTRATIVE'
            then i_errcount
        else 0
        end) as administrative_errors,
    sum(case 
        when c_errtype = 'FYI'
            then i_errcount
        else 0
        end) as FYI_errors
from EL_Error_Mst
group by i_empid
```